# multiplying sin waves / cos waves recursively in a loop in matlab / octave

Tags: matlab, for-loop, recursion, octave, trigonometry

I'm trying to multiply sin waves / cosine waves recursively but I'm not sure why my answers are so different.  *Y2* in **blue** is what I'm trying to get but the FOR loop which is *Y* in **red** is what is produced any idea how to fix the FOR loop *Y*? see plot and code below ?

```
Fs = 8000;% Sampling frequency
t=linspace(0,1,Fs);

y=zeros(1,length(t));
y = .5*sin(2*pi*2*t); 
for ii=1:1:3    
    y=y.*y; 
end
plot(y,'r') 
hold on

y2=(.5*sin(2*pi*2*t)).* (.5*sin(2*pi*2*t)).*(.5*sin(2*pi*2*t)); %should look like this
plot(y2,'b') %both plots should look like this
```

[image: Plot]
PS:  I'm using octave 3.8.1 which is like matlab

Comment: Your `for` loop is fine but your idea is wrong. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're multiplying eight times here

```
y = .5*sin(2*pi*2*t); 
for ii=1:1:3    
     y=y.*y;
```

`ii=1:1:3` is inclusive, so you do `y=y.*y` three times.

First time it becomes y = y^2,

Second time it become y^4 = y^2*y*2

Third time it becomes y^8 = y^4*y^4

---

This would be a solution:

```
Fs = 8000;% Sampling frequency
t=linspace(0,1,Fs);

y=zeros(1,length(t));
y = .5*sin(2*pi*2*t); 
result = ones(1,length(t));
for ii=1:1:3
     result=result.*y; 
end
plot(result,’r’) 
hold on

y2=(.5*sin(2*pi*2*t)).* (.5*sin(2*pi*2*t)).*(.5*sin(2*pi*2*t)); %should look like this
plot(y2,'b') %both plots should look like this
```

Answer (score 2):

In all iteration, y.*y make square of updated y.

```
Fs = 8000;% Sampling frequency
t=linspace(0,1,Fs);

y=ones(1,length(t));
x = .5*sin(2*pi*2*t); 
for ii=1:1:3    
    y=y.*x; 
end
plot(y,'r') 
hold on

y2=(.5*sin(2*pi*2*t)).* (.5*sin(2*pi*2*t)).*(.5*sin(2*pi*2*t)); %should look like this
plot(y2,'b') %both plots should look like this
```

Maybe, you want this code.

Comment: At least in Matlab you can even simplify to `y = y.^3;`. An explanation what he was doing wrong would also be good. ;)